# Changing app identity when app is created from another base app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I created an app for imaging application to start with.
Now I had to build another app which uses a lot of functionalities of the previous app.

I copied and pasted the first project, and changed the app Display Name, etc. in WMAppManifest.xml file.
But now when I try to deploy this app, I notice that the first app is replaced by this second one.

How can I resolve this? I suppose I require a different product/publisher ID for this app in Packing section. How do I obtain these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to "obtain" these IDs. When you submit your app to the marketplace, they are automatically replaced by the appropriate values. When developing on your computer, just put whatever value you want. The values are located in the application manifest (WMAppManifest.xml).

You can create a GUID in Visual Studio by going in the "Tools" menu, then clicking on "Create GUID".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the product ID (it's a GUID you can generate a new one).